# theme style not working on other screens and dialogs KIVY - KIVYMD

Tags: python, kivy, themes, kivymd

I created a button that changes the color of the application. In the main screen it works totally fine, however it does not change the color of the theme in the dialogs and in the other screens. I dont know if I need to change the color of theme manually in each screen (using screen manager) or in the dialagos I create.

Here is my code

```
class MainMenu(Screen):
   def build(self):
       self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Cyan"
       self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Indigo"  # Lime
       self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"

       sm.add_widget(SignInScreen(name='sign_in_screen'))
       sm.add_widget(MainMenu(name='main_menu'))
       sm.add_widget(TermsConditionsScreen(name='terms_conditions_screen'))
       sm.add_widget(MyInformation(name='my_information'))

       return sm

   def color_changer(self):
       if self.theme_cls.theme_style == "Dark":
           self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
           self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Cyan"
           self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Indigo"
       elif self.theme_cls.theme_style == "Light":
           self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
           self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "DeepPurple"
           self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Teal"
```

Here are some screenshots of my problem (In the last picture, the color of the text is white)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to set them in the `build` method of `App`'s instance, they should work consistently everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit properties of `theme_cls` in `App`/`MDApp`'s instance to make all other screens apply changes to their theme. Changing it in `Screen`'s instance, as in your example `class MainMenu(Screen)`, will only change that screen's theme.